# why keyword argument are not passed into __init_subclass__(..)

Tags: python, metaclass

Code:

```
class ExternalMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, base, dct, **kwargs):
        dct['district'] = 'Jiading'
        x = super().__new__(cls, name, base, dct)
        x.city = 'Shanghai'
        return x


class MyMeta(ExternalMeta):
    def __new__(cls, name, base, dct, age=0, **kwargs):
        x = super().__new__(cls, name, base, dct)
        x.name = 'Jerry'
        x.age = age
        return x

    def __init__(self, name, base, dct, age=0, **kwargs):
        self.country = 'China'


class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta, age=10):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, say_hi, **kwargs):
        print(f'keyword arguments are: {kwargs}')
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.hello = say_hi


class DerivedClass(MyClass, say_hi="hello"):
    pass
```

this throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app2.py", line 27, in <module>
    class DerivedClass(MyClass, say_hi="hello"):
  File "app2.py", line 11, in __new__
    x = super().__new__(cls, name, base, dct)
  File "app2.py", line 4, in __new__
    x = super().__new__(cls, name, base, dct)
TypeError: __init_subclass__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'say_hi'
```

From the offical doc:

> classmethod object.**init_subclass**(cls)
> This method is called whenever the containing class is subclassed. cls is then the new subclass. If defined as a normal instance method, this method is implicitly converted to a class method.

> Keyword arguments which are given to a new class are passed to the parent’s class **init_subclass**. For compatibility with other classes using **init_subclass**, one should take out the needed keyword arguments and pass the others over to the base class, as in:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__

I try to print kwargs, it's {}, empty, so why my say_hi, arguments are not passed to **init_subclass** method?

edit:
I read more materials and write an article with diagrams and tests about the creation of instance and classes in Python:

http://shanwq.com/?p=154

Reference to articles(including this page) are included in it, hopes it can help anyone.

Comment: Btw you don't call the metacls init which is a big boo boo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python exposes the mechanisms classes are created in the form of customizable meta-classes - and does not perform any magic beyond that.

Which means: there is no "hidden channel" through which the keyword arguments of a class are passed to `__init_subclass__` - that is done inside Python's `type.__new__` call.

When using `__init_subclass__`  one will typically do not combine it with a metaclass (one of the idea of the creation of the former was to reduce the need for metaclasses at all).

In this case, you do use a metaclass, and you  **supress** the keyword arguments in the call to `type.__new__`: there are no arguments it can convey to `__init_subclass__`.

Simply pass the arguments there, and Python will be able to pass them down to `__init_subclass__`:

```
...
class ExternalMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, base, dct, **kwargs):
        dct['district'] = 'Jiading'
        # Forward the kwargs here:
        x = super().__new__(cls, name, base, dct, **kwargs)
        x.city = 'Shanghai'
        return x


class MyMeta(ExternalMeta):
    def __new__(cls, name, base, dct, age=0, **kwargs):
        # and here:
        x = super().__new__(cls, name, base, dct, **kwargs)
        x.name = 'Jerry'
        x.age = age
        return x
...
```

The extra kwargs arguments are also passed to the metaclass' `__init__` method. But they follow a different "pipe". I will try to summarize the whole thing here:

1. Keyword arguments are declared in the class statement. (ex. `class MyClass(MyBase1, metaclass=MyMeta, extraarg="foobar"):`
2. The Python runtime will check the bases for the class and any "metaclass" argument to calculate the metaclass (if there is a metaclass conflict it will raise a typeerror)
3. Python will then call the metaclass `__prepare__` method, passing any extra arguments it got and use its return value as the namespace in which the class body will be executed (by default an ordinary dict)
4. some special attributes (like `__module__`, `__qualname__` and `__anotations__` (with an empty dictionary)) are assigned in the namespace.
5. the class body itself is executed: declared methods are created as functions and class attributes are assigned in the namespace provided by `__prepare__`.
6. After the class body is executed, attribute annotations are assigned in the namespace `__annotations__` entry, one by one. (not in any spec, could as well happen as each attribute is encountered, and is subject to change with PEP 649 implementation for Python 3.13)
7. The Python runtime will *call* the metaclass ("MyMeta"
   in the example) passing it all arguments and keyword arguments, *but* for the argument named `metaclass` itself.
8. Calling the metaclass means the `__call__` method of the *class* of the *metaclass* will be executed. (The "twice removed metaclass" or "metametaclass"). This is ordinarily `type` itself, and is not usually customized, but for learning purposes.
9. This `__call__` method will get all the arguments and call the metaclass `__new__` (this step is detailed bellow) and, if that returns an instance of the metaclass (i.e. an ordinary class), call the metaclass `__init__` method - always passing the mandatory arguments + any named arguments.
10. The `__new__` method on the metaclass have, at some point, to call the super `type.__new__` method: it is the only way for code written in Python (as opposed to code in an extension) to create a new class. In a custom metaclass, like in this example, the developer can remove, add or pre-process any extra arguments as desired - and forward them to `type.__new__`.
11. `type.__new__` in turn will: (1)calculate the class "MRO" (Method resolution order) (and yes, again - it was done prior to determine the metaclass, but the runtime has to confirm that a linearized MRO is possible here), including calling special methods for that, if one of the bases is a not a class, but features a `__mro_entries__` special method, (2)  create a new instance of the class,(3) call any existing descriptors in the passed namespace `__set_name__` function, (4) call the class's most derived `__init_subclass__` (i.e. the first `__init_subclass__` it finds in a superclass), passing any extra arguments it got and (5) return the newly created class (to the "metametaclass" `__call__`)
12. The metaclass `__init__` is called, also with any extra arguments. By default it is `type.__init__` which does nothing.
13. The "metametaclass" `__call__` returns the class that was returned by the metaclass `__new__` call to the runtime
14. if there are any class decorators, they are called with this returned class object
15. the name given in the class statement is assigned to the class returned above in the context of the statement.

```
class MetaMeta(type):
    def __call__(mcls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Meta-meta-class __call__ with {mcls}, {args}, {kwargs}")
        result = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("returning from meta-meta-class __call__")
        return result

class Meta(type, metaclass=MetaMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(mcls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Metaclass __prepare__ with {mcls}, {args}, {kwargs}")
        class VerboseDict(dict):
            def __init__(self, name):
                self.name = name
            def __setitem__(self, name, value):
                print(f"{self.name} assignment {name}={value}")
                if name == "__annotations__":
                    value = VerboseDict("   annotations")
                super().__setitem__(name, value)
        return VerboseDict("ns")
    
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, ns, **kwargs):
        print(f"metaclass __new__ with {mcls}, {name}, {bases}, {ns}, {kwargs}")
        result = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, ns, **kwargs)
        print(f"Returning from the metaclass `__new__`")
        return result
    def __init__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"metaclass __init__ with {cls}, {args}, {kwargs}")
        return super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"metaclass __call__ (creating an instance) with {cls}, {args}, {kwargs}")
        return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

class Descriptor:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return 23
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        print(f"Descriptor __set_name__ with {self}, {owner}, {name}")

def decorator(cls):
    print(f"class decorator with {cls}")
    return cls

class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        # one can't pass extra kwargs to this call: it will raise TypeError
        super().__init_subclass__()
        print(f"{__class__} __init_subclass__ with {cls}, {kwargs}")

@decorator
class MyClass(Base, metaclass=Meta, extra="foobar"):
    a = "foobar"
    b = Descriptor()
    c: int = 0
    d: str
    def e(self):
        __class__ # triggers the creatin of "__classcell__" attr in the namespace
```

Output:

```
Metaclass __prepare__ with <class '__main__.Meta'>, ('MyClass', (<class '__main__.Base'>,)), {'extra': 'foobar'}
ns assignment __module__=__main__
ns assignment __qualname__=MyClass
ns assignment __annotations__={}
ns assignment a=foobar
ns assignment b=<__main__.Descriptor object at 0x7f47415f49e0>
ns assignment c=0
   annotations assignment c=<class 'int'>
   annotations assignment d=<class 'str'>
ns assignment e=<function MyClass.e at 0x7f4740c27880>
ns assignment __classcell__=<cell at 0x7f47415f4280: empty>
Meta-meta-class __call__ with <class '__main__.Meta'>, ('MyClass', (<class '__main__.Base'>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'MyClass', '__annotations__': {'c': <class 'int'>, 'd': <class 'str'>}, 'a': 'foobar', 'b': <__main__.Descriptor object at 0x7f47415f49e0>, 'c': 0, 'e': <function MyClass.e at 0x7f4740c27880>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x7f47415f4280: empty>}), {'extra': 'foobar'}
metaclass __new__ with <class '__main__.Meta'>, MyClass, (<class '__main__.Base'>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'MyClass', '__annotations__': {'c': <class 'int'>, 'd': <class 'str'>}, 'a': 'foobar', 'b': <__main__.Descriptor object at 0x7f47415f49e0>, 'c': 0, 'e': <function MyClass.e at 0x7f4740c27880>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x7f47415f4280: empty>}, {'extra': 'foobar'}
Descriptor __set_name__ with <__main__.Descriptor object at 0x7f47415f49e0>, <class '__main__.MyClass'>, b
<class '__main__.Base'> __init_subclass__ with <class '__main__.MyClass'>, {'extra': 'foobar'}
Returning from the metaclass `__new__`
metaclass __init__ with <class '__main__.MyClass'>, ('MyClass', (<class '__main__.Base'>,), {'__module__': '__main__', '__qualname__': 'MyClass', '__annotations__': {'c': <class 'int'>, 'd': <class 'str'>}, 'a': 'foobar', 'b': <__main__.Descriptor object at 0x7f47415f49e0>, 'c': 0, 'e': <function MyClass.e at 0x7f4740c27880>, '__classcell__': <cell at 0x7f47415f4280: Meta object at 0x1e57400>}), {'extra': 'foobar'}
returning from meta-meta-class __call__
class decorator with <class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

Comment: it does solve the problem. But, still confusing about argument passing between, `__new__(..)`, `__init__(..)`, and `__init_subclass__(..)`, does the` __init__(..)` has the same arguments as `__new__`? does `__init_subclass__ `has parts of argument of` __new__`(since it get them from `__new__`)? if yes how `__new__` decide which arguments are passed?

Comment: That is somewhat complicated  - I even had drafted another paragraph with that, but I thought it would complicate things - - I will rewrite it at the end of the answer.

Comment: That's a lot information here, and great answer!  is it true that `__prepare__`, `__call__` are `classmethod`, `__new__` are `staticmethod`, while `__init__` is instance method, since i notice their argument passing is different. Also, why the `__call__` method of `Meta` not being executed?

Comment: Yes - __prepare__ has to be expliciy listed as a classmethod. __init_subclass__ is imocotly a class method and __new__ is a static method. The others are all instance methods, including __call__ - but for a method on a metaclass, the instance is the created class, so we use CLS instead of self.

Comment: And the __call__ method on the metaclass is not called because it would be called when instantiating the created class. Try to create an instance of MyClass and you will see it.

Comment: so whenever a instance( whether it's instance of metaclass, or instance of class) is instantiated, the `__call__` method of the metaclass of the instance's class is called? that's interesting, i can do something in here, what does the default do? just do `super().__call__`?

Comment: Yes. For an ordinary class instance, the class is called (like in `MyClass()` (<- it is just the same as a function call), and this actually executes the class' `__call__` method, which lives in its metaclass. What it does is call the class `__new__` and `__init__` in turn. Unlike `type.__new__`, `type.__call__` does not need to be called with a `super()` - you can completly customize the way you call `__new__` and `__init__` and add more code/calls checks anywhere there - just return the new instance at the end.

Comment: I even once created a metaclass that allowed classes to have async `__new__` and `__init__` methods, so that an instance can be created asynchronously. It is in an answer in Portuguese S.O., but the code should be readable: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/390755/%c3%89-poss%c3%advel-definir-como-async-o-m%c3%a9todo-inicializador-de-uma-classe-em-python/390895#390895

Comment: in step 8 `Calling the metaclass means the __call__ method of the class of the metaclass will be executed. `,  does this mean first calling the `__call__` method of metaclass, then by default inside this function it calls `__call__` of metametaclass(MetaMeta in your example)? or it directly call `__call__` method of MetaMeta? also does `super` keyword also applies for meta class, from my knowledge, it's only used for inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Both `ExternalMeta.__new__` and `MyMeta.__new__` *accept* arbitrary keyword arguments (including `say_hi`), but neither passes them on to `super().__new__`. It's `type.__new__` that actually causes `__init_subclass__` to be called, but it never receives `say_hi` in order to pass it on.

The solution is to simply pass `**kwargs` to the call to `super().__new__` so that whoever needs them will get them.

```
class ExternalMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, base, dct, **kwargs):
        dct['district'] = 'Jiading'
        x = super().__new__(cls, name, base, dct, **kwargs)
        x.city = 'Shanghai'
        return x


class MyMeta(ExternalMeta):
    def __new__(cls, name, base, dct, age=0, **kwargs):
        x = super().__new__(cls, name, base, dct, **kwargs)
        x.name = 'Jerry'
        x.age = age
        return x

    def __init__(self, name, base, dct, age=0, **kwargs):
        self.country = 'China'


class MyClass(metaclass=MyMeta, age=10):
    def __init_subclass__(cls, say_hi, **kwargs):
        print(f'keyword arguments are: {kwargs}')
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.hello = say_hi


class DerivedClass(MyClass, say_hi="hello"):
    pass
```